# javascript on div id click close parent div and child div element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a message div class like so:

```
<div class="message_box_prompt">
    <div class="boxclose" id="boxclose"  onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">&#10006;</div>
    This is a message
</div>;
```

If my user clicks my div `boxclose` this closes the message box `message_box_prompt` and also removes the div `boxclose`.

```
onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
```

My problem is I have more than one occurrence of my div class `message_box_prompt` showing on the page at once:

Occurrence 1

```
<div class="message_box_prompt">
    <div class="boxclose" id="boxclose"  onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">&#10006;</div>
    This is a message
</div>;
```

Occurrence 2

```
<div class="message_box_prompt">
    <div class="boxclose" id="boxclose"  onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">&#10006;</div>
    This is a message
</div>;
```

Occurrence 3

```
<div class="message_box_prompt">
    <div class="boxclose" id="boxclose"  onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">&#10006;</div>
    This is a message
</div>;
```

I only want the div the user clicks on to close. I don't want it to close any of the others, instead at the moment if my user clicks on one `message_box_prompt` div to close it they all close.

Can someone show me a better way of doing this so I can make it do what I want?Thanks

Comment: You are using the same id for both divs. IDs should be unique.http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp . Try work with class instead

Comment: It works as you written (although as Clyff said, you IDs should be unique to follow best practices for coding) but here's a demo of your code as is: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/280/ . is there a way you can show us a demo of what isn't working for you?

Answer (score 3):

If using [**JQuery**](https://jquery.com/) this may help out

**Parent**: https://api.jquery.com/parent/ (if you need it)

**Hide**: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

I would suggest, just like the comment, give each child unique Id's, then that would make this next code so easy to use.

```
$("#uniqueID").hide();
```

Or pure Javascript

```
document.getElementById('uniqueID').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is malformed, you have a redundant

```
</div>';
```

and for some reason a '; at then end of it. You are also repeating the same ID, but that's not part of the problem, because you are using the this keyword. I do not know why you are having a problem where they are all closing, seems to be working fine in the jsfiddle I put it in.

```
<div class="message_box_prompt">
    <div 
        class="boxclose"
        onclick="this.parentNode.remove();"
    >&#10006;</div>
    <p>Message 1</p>
</div>
<div class="message_box_prompt">
    <div 
        class="boxclose"
        onclick="this.parentNode.remove();"
    >&#10006;</div>
    <p>Message 2</p>
</div>
<div class="message_box_prompt">
    <div 
        class="boxclose"
        onclick="this.parentNode.remove();"
    >&#10006;</div>
    <p>Message 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, maybe having the same ID is not a part of (that) problem, but it's a good practice to use a unique ID for each element (including the `message_box_prompt` and the `boxclose` divs). Furthermore, in IE, you're likely to get (lots of) problems if more than one element has the same ID (even if the problems are not related to what you're trying to accomplish).

Also, remember that `remove` is different from `hide` even if visually, they do the same.

Comment: Yes I know id's should be unique, that's why I removed them. If I where to keep them then they would have to be unique. I just knew that problem was not part of the issue at hand, because Mark is using this which in this case is what grabs the element. Unless he is doing something else those id's are not needed at all. If it where my code I would likely use css to hide, and show them rather then use remove, and I would also avoid inline event attachment. But that's me.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<div class="message_box_prompt">

<div class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden'">&#10006;This is a message</div>

<div class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden'">&#10006;This is a message</div>

<div class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden'">&#10006;This is a message</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery:

```
$(".boxclose").on("click",function(){
    $(this).parent().hide(0)
    $(this).remove();        
});
```